# Plugin for create a image and video galleries

Tags: wordpress

I needed some plugin (or theme) where they could create galleries with pictures, videos, and if possible only with text, and then you can adapt the code. For code example, needed to create a carousel that has 5 images, 2 videos and 3 blocks of text (optional).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Flexslider by WooThemes: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Best damn slider ever, period.